# How to resolve EPERM: operation not permitted error in webpack command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webpack, frontend

How to resolve EPERM: operation not permitted error in webpack command?

The following error message occurs when using webpack.
PS C:\Workspace\Mission> npm run dev

```
 > webpack-demo@1.0.0 dev
 > webpack --mode=development

[webpack-cli] [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Workspace\Mission\dist\px.bundle.js'] {
   errno: -4048,
   code: 'EPERM',
   syscall: 'open',
   path: 'C:\\Workspace\\Mission\\dist\\px.bundle.js'
}
```

Running the `npm cache clean --force` command works fine.
However, if I run the npm run dev command 3 or 4 times, the same error repeats again.

I gave the account admin rights, and I also gave full control to the folder. I tried running it in admin mode, but it didn't work.

How to fix this error?